# Playing with magnetic lines

Tags: magnetic-fields

My question is simple , I was just curious about this this it might seem stupid question but it should be thought upon , i was asking can we concentrate all magnetic lines at one place.
Thanks in advance for giving your answer.

Comment: A bar magnet does not have all magnetic field lines in one place.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but I was trying  to ask that how can we concentrate magnetic field of bar magnet at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a magnetic monopole then it will be a source or sink for magnetic field lines.

We have not observed such a thing. This statement is equivalent to one of Maxwell's equations: $\nabla\cdot B=0.$

If you are asking about magnetic field lines crossing, think about the meaning of these field lines. These are lines of force, so it would imply that the force at a point of intersection would have multiple directions.